# How can I enable Hold-to-Scope (quickscoping)?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

By default, I can only toggle aiming down scope.

What setting do I pick so I can hold down right mouse to aim?

Comment: Have you checked your input settings?

Comment: I am surprised at the votes saying "too broad" and "unclear" - this is an extremely clear question, with only one answer.

Comment: I voted as too broad because OP had not listed what their current settings were set too. Also, @Jeeva, keep in mind that platform tags are for questions deliberately asking about a specific platform. For questions where the platform itself changes the context, simply having the platform in the question body is enough

Answer (score 1):

In Black Ops 2, you will need to rebind a button to "ADS" (Aim Down Sight).

By default, `Mouse 2` is bound to "Toggle ADS" (shown below) - you can replace this bind under Options -> Controls -> Combat.

[image: CoD:BO2 Options, Controls, Combat menu]